# How to get segmentation algorithms to identify regularly repeating patterns

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am looking for defects in a structure that can be difficult even for a human to detect. I'm using segmentation algorithms (e.g. Mask RCNN, UNet) to do this. Sometimes the structure will have regularly repeating holes in it that look like defects but are not. A human can see that they are regularly repeating and therefore not likely to be true defects. Is there a way for a deep learning algorithm to take advantage of this same information? In theory, I could write an algorithm that runs after the deep learning algorithm to look for this pattern, but the regularities are dissimilar-enough (e.g. in the spacing distance) that I don't expect this to work well. Is there a way to get, say, a semantic segmentation model to learn to recognize (and skip) this type of pattern? There are examples in the training data, but I don't think the networks can grasp this larger pattern.